# IF Formula with multiple conditions

Tags: excel

I am trying to write a formula that says:

IF C2 is less than C3, `1 load`, or
IF C2 is greater than C3 but less than or equal to C3*2, `2 loads`, or
IF C2 is greater than C3*2 but less than or equal to C3*3, `3 loads`.

Answer (score 2):

that can be simply written as

```
=CEILING(C2,C3)/C3&" Loads"
```

you round the number up to the nearest  full load and then you divide it by the load size so it will always work even past 3 loads

Comment: +1 you beat me to it.  For the singular/plural though, this should work: `=CEILING(C2,C3)/C3&" Load"&IF(C2>C3,"s","")`